# How to navigate to different folder in prebuilt Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using a prebuilt container from Dockerhub. When I run the container it acts like it's in a folder called `workspace`, since my run command `sudo docker run -it shubhamgoel/birds:bigbang bash` returns  `root@eg2e775g0a1b:/workspace#`

I don't know how to navigate to the correct folder. I need to run this container in a folder `/home/s/ucmr`.

If I do

`sudo docker run -it shubhamgoel/birds:bigbang bash -c "cd:/home/s/ucmr"`

I get

`bash: cd:/home/s/ucmr: No such file or directory`

How do I navigate to the correct folder with this prebuilt container? Thank you.

__

Edit: I've tried

`sudo docker run -v /kitty:/dog --name kittycat -it shubhamgoel/birds:bigbang`

and when I search for 'dog' on my disk there's no such folder. Also when I type in `mkdir frog` and search for 'frog' on my disk there's no such folder...

Comment: What does this has to do with python? Also please consider checking out [what topics can you ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question seems to be off topic here and is more suitable for [super user](https://superuser.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -it shubhamgoel/birds:bigbang bash -c "cd:/home/s/ucmr"` is wrong for 2 reasons. The first one has already been covered by the other answer (wrong syntax with `cd` command). The other is that using the `-it` docker option with a non-interactive bash is kind of meaningless. The `-c` bash option just means "execute whatever there is between the double quotes and return to the caller", this last part makes the interactivity vanish.
A first naive solution, but still working, could be creating another shell like this:

```
docker run -it shubhamgoel/birds:bigbang bash -c "cd /home/s/ucmr && bash"
```

However, docker is far smarter and flexible and lets you override some Dockerfile directive, for instance the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir):

```
docker run -it -w="/home/s/ucmr" shubhamgoel/birds:bigbang bash
```